# Custom off-topic reasons: what to use as #3?

Tags: discussion

The Stack Exchange sites like Signal Processing allow for three custom (and one default) off-topic reason.

The default is:

[image: Generic Off Topic]

and our currently-used two custom ones are:

[image: General Programming]

and

[image: Working to a spec]

There is currently an unapproved one relating to homework questions:

[image: Homework reason]

My question is: should we (the mods) approve this third custom option?  Or is there a better/more frequent custom off-topic reason?

Mods: The page to do this is [here.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic) Non-mods will get a Page Not Found error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the reason is common enough, but the text could use some streamlining. Maybe something like the following:

> This question appears to be homework. **Complete answers to homework
>   are off-topic**, but specific questions *about* homework are acceptable if they include 
>   enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Comment: Sounds good! I've updated the custom answer to say that. If you (or @jojek) are happy with it, can you please approve it? In needs more than one mod to make a change like this.